# "split 'em up with a movie" on the sitcom "Friends"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question about a sentence from the television sitcom *Friends*. The six are playing poker, and the girls lose.

> Phoebe: Alright, here's my $7.50. But I think you should know that this money is cursed.
>
> Joey: What?
>
> Phoebe: I cursed it. So now bad things will happen to he who spends it.
>
> Chandler: That's alright, I'll take it. Bad things happen to me anyway. This way I can 
>     split 'em up with a movie.

I can't understand the this line. How are bad things related to a movie? What does it mean to "split 'em up"? Does it mean by watching a movie he can escape the doom?

Comment: He just means that bad things happen to him repeatedly, and that's not going to change. But at least having the money will enable him to enjoy watching a movie in between the previous and the next bad thing.

Answer (score 5):

Movie tickets cost around $7.50 so in this sentence Chandler is implying that he would spend the $7.50 on a movie. Since movies are good things, and bad things happen all the time, he would be mixing things up by adding a good thing (the movie) to his otherwise wretched life. He is thus planning on 'splitting up' the *sequence* of bad things that happen to him with a good thing (the movie).